# Grapping first image from Facebook Page using cURL and PHP DOM

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, dom, curl

I am trying to fetch the first images on a Facebook Page. It works on other websites - using:

`$image = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);`

But for some reason, Facebook have wrapped in the 's i need, like this:

`<code class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_7"><!-- <div class="timelineLoggedOutSignUp"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_loggedout_sign_up" data-referrer="pagelet_loggedout_sign_up"></div></div><div class="fbTimelineTopSectionBase  fbTimelineLoggedOutTopSection"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_above_header_timeline" data-referrer="pagelet_above_header_timeline"></div><div id="above_header_timeline_placeholder"></div><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineTopSection"><div id="fbProfileCover"><div class="cover" id="u_0_4"><a class="coverWrap coverImage" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=632540440113248&amp;set=a.540825239284769.1073741827.540818775952082&amp;type=1" rel="theater" ajaxify="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=632540440113248&amp;set=a.540825239284769.1073741827.540818775952082&amp;type=1&amp;src=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ash3%2F579116_632540440113248_872174037_n.png&amp;size=851%2C315&amp;source=10" title="Coverbillede" id="fbCoverImageContainer"><img class="coverPhotoImg photo img" src="https://scon`

Note that it is wrapped into a: `<!--  -->`.

Is there some way I can avoid this? Maybe changing the user-agent to an older browser, where they dont use the `<!-- -->` wraps? I can do this, using `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` in my CURL settings.

Any ideas? I am quite lost here..

Answer (score 0):

All of this data is available via the Facebook Graph API so you don't need to fiddle around with the DOM or scrape the page - and you don't need to be authenticated to get it. This means you don't need Facebook's SDK or need to worry about registering an application if you are just grabbing public info. Also, Facebook change their HTML all the time so scraping the content will slowly drive you mad.

A quick JS example below, this gets the cover photo for your page:

```
$('#GetCoverImage').click(function() {
    $.getJSON(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/EduKarmaDK',
        function(pageData) {
            console.log(pageData.cover.source);
        }
    );
});
```

Other public info about the page is available in the pageData object. Have a play around with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=EduKarmaDK) to see what else is available.

PHP example:

```
<?php

    $pageData = json_decode(
        file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/EduKarmaDK')
    );

    echo($pageData->cover->source);
```